# why preventDefault, stopPropogation, stopImmediatePropogation dont work with some elements?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, click, preventdefault, stoppropagation

i code an chrome extension and I need that on any site, when you click on any element, no action occurs on them, but they are painted over in a certain color

I first used preventDefault, then added stopPropagation and stopImmediatePropogation and it didn’t work. Rather it doesn't work on some elements,  that is, when clicked, it goes to another page.

```
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(elem => {
           elem.addEventListener('click', this.mouseclickBind);
        });
document.addEventListener('click', this.mouseclickBind);
```

```
mouseclickFunc(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        let elem = event.target;
        if (elem && this.illegalTags.indexOf(elem.tagName)) {
            if (elem.dataset.mark === this.mark_train) {
                delete elem.dataset.mark;
                this.selectedElems.pop(elem);

            } else {
                elem.dataset.mark = this.mark_train;
                this.selectedElems.push(elem);
            }
        }
    }
```

why does it happen? and how do I solve it?

Comment: Use `window.addEventListener` and add `,true` as explained [here](/a/70728151).